# How to make Scroller background transparent in NSScrollView?

Tags: swift, macos, nsscrollview, nsscroller

I've used Storyboard to set up the NSScrollView and I cannot find any option where I can disable the scroller's background. Any ideas on how to make this happen?

[image]

[image: NSScroller Background Color]

Comment: Subclass NSScroller.

Comment: Yes, I've Subclass NSScroller but AutoHideScroller does not work...

Comment: What version of macOS are you targeting?

Comment: version 10.13.5

Answer (score 3):

**Basically idea behind this is subclass the NSScroller and then make changes accordingly.**

I had the same requirement so I subclassed it and did the changes as shown.
objective c code is converted with help of online tool so apologies for mistakes
and have look.

this may help.

```
//  Converted to Swift 4 by Swiftify v4.1.6766 - https://objectivec2swift.com/
//  GridScroller.h
//  Created by Vikram on 08/09/16.

import Cocoa

class OpaqGridScroller: NSScroller {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        NSColor.clear.setFill()
        dirtyRect.fill()
        // whatever style you want here for knob if you want
        knobStyle = .dark
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. However, I've Subclass NSScrollView. Have you tried?

Comment: yes, it is working fine at my side. set autohide to yes in IB and increase scroll content at run time and it will show the scroller accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try override draw scroller rect

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    NSDrawWindowBackground(bounds);
    self.drawKnob()
}
```

You always can draw custom rect color by setting it before

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    NSColor.clear.set()
    __NSRectFill(dirtyRect)

    self.drawKnob()
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works! but the NSScroller is clear, not dark which means it's not visible to see.

Comment: What version of MacOS you use?

Comment: macOS version: 10.13.3

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me.

```
class OpaqueGridScroller: NSScroller {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        // NSColor.clear.set()
        // dirtyRect.fill()
        self.drawKnob()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The foregoing answers that call `self.drawKnob()` are only partially correct.  The problem is that the knob should usually not be drawn at all if there's nothing to scroll in that direction.

For my solution, I sub-classed the vertical NSScroller (scroll bar) in a scrolling NSTextView, in order to override the scroll bar's `draw()` method, as above.  But when there was nothing to scroll, this draws a knob that has a length that's not correct.

So I added

```
 @IBOutlet var myScroller : NSScrollView!
```

as a property of the sub-classed NSScroller and wired it up in the storyboard, so that the scroller bar can know the NSScrollView that uses it, and then draw the scroll bar with

```
override draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)
{
    if myScroller.contentSize.height < myScroller.documentView!.bounds.height {
        self.drawKnob()
        }
}
```

The knob disappears when the NSScrollView is resized enough that there's nothing vertical to scroll, and re-appears when there is, while at the same time allowing whatever's in the background below it to show through.

I'm not sure if this is a hack, or the correct solution, but it seems to work as expected.